# Remove Characters from a String that doesn't comply with the Regex Rule

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to know how can I remove characters that doesn't fall into the ones allowed in my Regex expressions.

I use this regular expression which allows all charactes from any language, space and apostrophe, but all other characters are not allowed.

```
/[\u00C0-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FF\w \']/
```

I want to create a jquery function that **remove all the characters in an text input field that doesn't comply to that rule**. So for example: the dagger character `'‡'` is not allowed and therefore should be replaced with an empty string `''` (aka removed from the string).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for jQuery, javascript already has a `String.replace()` method:

```
str = str.replace(/[^\u00C0-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FF\w \']/g, '');
```

or just

```
str = str.replace(/\W/g, '');
```

Comment: I think you missed a ^ somewhere. Those are the characters OP wanted to keep.

Comment: That's remove all the characters that comply to this regex. I need those that don't comply

Comment: The first one is exactly what I need. The second one doesn't use my rule. Thanks adeneo. accepted